# Save Stacked Canvas as image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using just js and html5 canvas. I'm drawing with canvas multiple fill patterns with images in specific shapes (not rectangles).

I dearly would love to be able to do that in a single canvas, but alas I haven't figured it out yet.

I have however, figured out how to do multiple stacked canvas's. Each with their own pattern fill as a layer with an absolute position.

The final product is something I want viewers to right click and "Save As". But as you can guess by now, only the top layer gets saved.

I'm building it with Chrome in mind.

So the answers I'm looking for is a generic "how to do multiple pattern fills (repeating) in multiple shapes in one canvas" (that's the best answer!).

Or a generic "how to 'Save As' all stacked canvas layers as a .png"

Reminder: Just using Javascript and html.

The below works. I used arcs to simplify the shapes for posting. But as I mentioned, only canvas1 here gets saved as a png.

If theres a way to put this into a single canvas, please let me know. Else, how do I save all canvas layers?

(absolute 0x, 0y. z-index# matches canvas number)

```
var canvastest0 = document.getElementById('canvas0');
var ctx0 = canvastest0.getContext('2d');

ctx0.arc(100,100, 50, 0, Math.PI*2,true);
ctx0.arc(150,150, 50, 0, Math.PI*2,true);
ctx0.clip();
img0 = new Image();
img0.src="pattern0.png";
img0.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  ctx0.fillStyle = ctx0.createPattern(this, 'repeat') 
  ctx0.fill();
}, true);

var canvastest1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx1 = canvastest1.getContext('2d');

ctx1.arc(100,100, 25, 0, Math.PI*2,true);
ctx1.arc(150,150, 25, 0, Math.PI*2,true);
ctx1.clip();

img1 = new Image();
img1.src="pattern1.png";
img1.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  ctx1.fillStyle = ctx1.createPattern(this, 'repeat') 
  ctx1.fill();
}, true);
```

Comment: generic shape fill : `beginPath(); path1Commands();fill();beginPath();path2Commands();fill();repeat();` Multiple canvas as one : `visibleContext.drawImage(hiddenCanvas1,0,0);visibleContext.drawImage(hiddenCanvas2,0,0);repeat()`

Comment: @Kaiido "Generic shape fill : beginPath(); path1Commands(); fill(); beginPath(); path2Commands(); fill(); re‌​peat();"   I must have tried this wrong. It kept coming out as the second pattern only. How would you apply it to the code above?